# In Full-Site-Editing, edits made to the code in a template part are not showing

Tags: block-editor

I trying to get my head around FSE and template parts. I was able to create a header in the Gutenberg editor and copy the code to header.html. However, when I edit the header.html code directly in my text editor, e.g., add a dashicon, it doesn't show in the header on the site or in the editor.

Is the only way to add to header.html in the editor and then copy the code? In essence, header.html is really only a back-up? I can go backwards? Edit the html and have it work?

What am I missing?

Brad

Comment: do you have a template with the same name in your database? The DB overrides local HTML files, so if you've edited that template using the site editor you would need to export those changes. HTML file block templates are just starting points, once you start using the UI to edit them those edits are saved in the database and take precedent, otherwise how would you be able to use the site editor if it doesn't edit the files? And if it did edit them, how could you as a theme developer ever hope to do version control or do updates?

Comment: Never thought of looking the database. Duh! This answers my next couple of questions as well.

Comment: Interesting that WordPress doesn't save the settings in theme.json to the database. E.g., I set padding to 20px in theme.json, left the padding untouched in the site editor, saved and checked the DB: padding: 0. Of course, it did save the values when I used the sliders in the editor. IMO, it should save the theme.json values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's probably because you made edits in the site editor which created a template/template_part post in the database, and that's what's being used, not your original HTML.

Unlike PHP templates, the HTML files in a block theme are the *starting* points. Once a user makes changes/additions those changes are saved in the database and take precedence. You would need to export those changes back to HTML files and replace the ones in your theme with the new versions, or delete the posts in the site editor.

It's generally best to use the site editor to make your changes, not the raw HTML. Some blocks may start to fail block validation if you deviate too much, and user changes might cause data loss when your changes don't map to anything a block normally generates. Lots of custom HTML blocks also makes your theme unintuitive and difficult to work with.

From what I can tell this is the precedence order:

- DB user template for current active theme
- HTML template file in child theme
- HTML template file in parent theme
- PHP template in child theme
- PHP template in parent theme

Do confirm this though as I'm not 100%

Comment: It sounds like I need to take off my coding hat and just embrace the editor. I never thought of looking the database for the template name, but now I see them. Thanks for that tip.

Comment: it's best to get as close as you possibly can using the editor UI, and expect that your users will try to use it too, if you can account for that then you can go wild elsewhere. Block varians/styles/patterns help a lot, as do custom blocks, but don't use custom blocks as a crutch if core blocks can be combined to give the same result

Comment: We must choose between web development and WordPress development as they try to make WP some kind of Squarespace no-code system.